# Python SQLite3 executemany: query that simulates set(data) - set(initial_data)

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Let's suppose I have some data in an Sqlite3 DB which is inserted by executing `executemany()` from Python's `sqlite3` module.

Example `initial_data`:

```
initial_data = [
    ('aa', 'test1', 'home1'),
    ('aa', 'test2', 'home2'),
    ('aa', 'test3', 'home3'),
    ('aa', 'test4', 'home4'),
    ('aa', 'test5', 'home5'),
]
```

Example `executemany()`:

```
self.db.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO some_table (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
""", data)
```

After inserting the above `initial_data` into the table, I might have a new set of `data` which looks like this:

```
data = [
    ('aa', 'test1', 'home1'),
    ('aa', 'test2', 'home2'),
    ('aa', 'test3', 'home3'),
    ('aa', 'test6', 'home6'),  // this is new
    ('aa', 'test4', 'home4'),
    ('aa', 'test5', 'home5'),
]
```

As you have probably noticed, there's a new row in `data` which is the only one that should be inserted into my table.

Now, I know I can do something like `set(data) - set(initial_data)` (if `len(data) > len(initial_data)`) and insert just that into my table, but I was wondering if I can alter in some way my query so that I can do this directly from SQL. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

*PS: Dunno if it matters, but `len(data)` will always be 30k-50k.*

Comment: You could use a merge or upsert query if you have primary keys. Updates only take time when something really needs updated

Comment: Assuming your table has a primary key or unique constraint that will catch those duplicates, an `INSERT OR IGNORE` should do the trick. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **INSERT IGNORE** query.

```
self.db.executemany("""
    INSERT IGNORE INTO some_table (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
""", data)
```